# Add event to secondary Google calendar

Tags: gmail, calendar, google-calendar

I often receive invites to events via Gmail, and wish to add them to one of my calendars in Google.  When I click 'add to calendar' (or equivalent), I see the usual drop-down to allow me to choose between calendars.  When I click on this drop-down, however, the only option is my primary calendar (the one with the same name as my Google account).

So...is there a way to add events to one of my other calendars, or do I just have to make a copy of the event if I want it outside my Google account primary calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember rightly, you have to add it do the calendar of the logged in user and then move it to any other linked calendar for which you have write access.

Comment: that seems to work, but does create a duplicate, which alerts the person that created the event that I can't attend if I delete it..  wish there were a more direct approach!

Comment: Know what you mean. Personally, I think Google have lost the plot with Calendar. Or rather, they've lost interest and everything is now poured into Google+. I'm seriously considering dumping it.